# How to safely persist logged-in state of user in React website?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies, react-redux

I have a website that runs on `example.com`. The website makes AJAX calls to my backend API which sits at `api.example.com`.

I employ a double-submit verification strategy for my authentication.

The backend has protected endpoints which check the JWT token with each request. The JWT token is stored in a `httpOnly` cookie. It also contains the CSRF token.

Alongside the JWT cookie I also send a CSRF cookie which is **not** `httpOnly`.
Each request that the client makes must contain the value of this cookie in a special header.

So far so good, but, I want to make sure that the client does everything in its power to prevent users from making pointless unauthenticated requests. So in my React app I have declared a few **private routes** which check if the user is logged in and if they are not, the user is redirected to the login page. The logged-in state is kept in the Redux store.

**The issue is that on a full refresh the Redux store is reset.** So as I see it, my options are:

**Option 1) Check the existence of a CSRF cookie**

The way I check if a user is authenticated is by checking if they have the CSRF cookie; I also do this during the store initialisation. If they do have the cookie, they are allowed to navigate to the protected page. All subsequent requests on this page are still verified on the backend for a JWT and CSRF token.

**Option 2) Check against the backend each time**

I can create a simple endpoint on the backend that is used to check if the user is logged in. So instead of just checking the cookie, the client can submit a request to this endpoint and verify that the token in the cookie is still valid.

**Option 3) Persist the Redux store**

I could implement a persisted store (there are some libraries that do this out there) so that the initial problem is automatically resolved, i.e.: the logged-in state is preserved upon full refresh. However, this yields a bunch of issues with caching and token expiration and it may not be worth the effort.